# Body request with Slim Framework(v4) returning null

Tags: php, api

Im trying to retrieve body parameters from a POST request using [Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/objects/request.html#the-request-body), but it's just returning `null` and i don't know why.

#### My structure follows:

**Index.php (router file)**

```php
<?php

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;

use Api\Middleware\Auth;

require __DIR__ . '../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = AppFactory::create();

$app->post('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    $parsedBody = $request->getParsedBody();
    $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($parsedBody));
    return $response;
})->add(new Auth);

$app->run();
```

**Request Structure**

```
{
    "test": "testing"
}
```

**Return**

> null